# How to add a watermark to images in Plone 5?

Tags: python-imaging-library, plone, plone-5.x

I've been thinking to add a new Dexterity content type and write views that serve a watermarked version of the original image using PIL.

But before jumping right to the code editor:

Is there any add-on I could use in Plone 5 to add a watermark to all views of an image, except for the main @@view?

Comment: Whay you mean with "all views of an image"?

Answer (score 1):

Just get coding, but here's [this](https://gist.github.com/djowett/00edf2c2f2db2c6f538cc2613d60a070) for starters.  It uses PIL to rotate a supplied image 10 degrees.  This provides 2 image fields - the editable original image, and the read only rotated one.  I'm sure you could adapt it to your usecase fairly easily.

It's Dexterity based, but with elements of grok which you will want to remove I guess.